# Wordpress Multisite: как добавить сайт к существующему?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-multisite

Есть сайт mysite.ru. Захотелось к нему добавлять поддомены, которые будут копиями главного сайта, только с разным названием городов.
Зарегистрирован поддомен с городом krasnodar.mysite.ru.
Надо используя одну админку основного сайта mysite.ru, подключать домены других городов как-то. Т.е. не залезая на всякие FTP, ничего не загружая ни на какие реальные поддомены, тупо добавляя поддомен в админке сайта mysite.ru, иметь рабочий поддомен-клон основного сайта с одной общей админкой и темой, заменяя автоматически только название города на поддомене (возможно в дальнейшем ещё какие-то параметры типа адреса, телефона и т.д.).

Погуглил, использую Wordpress Multisite (т.е. опция в wp-admin, сам сайт не переустанавливал никак). Добавил там поддомен. Наверное нужно указать, какую тему использовать? Но существующая тема на сайте не отображается [image: тут]:

Добавить её тоже нельзя, т.к. оно пишет, что такая тема уже есть. В настройках сайта-поддомена я указал название темы [image: тут]

Сам сайт krasnodar.mysite.ru пустой (пустая страница).
Возможно ли при таких условиях сделать то, что требуется?

Я не шарю в серверных делах, решил попробовать, чтобы не отказываться, если не слишком сложно.
Если дело касается только галочек в админке, то нормально. Если дело касается уже серверных настроек, то я лучше откажусь от этого дела, т.к. не по зубам будет. Или что-то подойдёт другое для этого дела?

Answer (score 1):

NS Cloner плагин используйте.
Он копирует основной сайт на поддомен или в подпапку
Зависит от того, как вы настроили Multisite